# Loading Bitmap Efficiently in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have dug insanely deep into this topic and found out a lot of options that makes the bitmap loading easier. But what I want to achieve is a lil far-fetched. I have referred this [video] which helps in loading the bitmaps efficiently. My question is unique cause I am able to load n number of bitmap images without any glitches but the problem is that it loads the **SAME** image[1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rsQet4nBVi8).

**CODE :**

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
...
in = httpConn.getInputStream();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inBitmap = image;
options.inSampleSize = 1;
image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in,null,options);
item = new RowItem(image, product_name, cost,product_id, dream_status,username); --> item is an object of holder class which has get and set methods
rowItems.add(item); --> this is an arraylist object of type holder class
```

}

Here I have a loop that loads 10 images from WebService, and I am setting it in a adapter at onPostExecute of an async task. When I loop through the 10 images, what happens to me is that, only the last image(10th image) gets set in the view and it gets repeated for all the 10 images. This is due to the following line :

```
options.inBitmap = image;
```

which recycles the bitmap. My question here is that, how can I use the inBitmap function and set all the images ? I mean the logic or loop that would let me set not only the 10th image but all the other images. Any help would be highly appreciated guys.I'll be happy to help if you guys have any queries.

**NOTE :** I am well aware of the fact that **inSampleSize** should always be set in powers of 2 but setting it to 2 reduces the size of my image and setting it to 1 is what meets my expectation.

Comment: Have you tried to use Universal Image Loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: I have already got an external library that lets me load infinite bitmap images, I just want to know how to pull this out.

Comment: where you are seeting the bitmap image.. Put that part also.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a BitmapPool class to smarten up the way you cache and re-use bitmaps. In your example, this pool could start off with a size of 10, and will cache 10 bitmaps. The pool size can grow or shrink depending on the implementation.

- you may request a bitmap from this Pool, via getBitmap(), and
- Bitmap obtained via getBitmap() call can be used as "inBitmap" while decoding the image
- you may return the bitmap back to the pool once you are done using/drawing its contents via returnBitmap()

You can extend the use of BitmapPool to facilitate other bitmap requests in your app.